# IP tables TEE command changes source mac address

Tags: linux, docker, networking, iptables

I am trying to forward/clone traffic from my host machine to my docker container using IPtables command.

I am able to receive traffic inside my container via iptables TEE command. However, this command changes the ethernet header by replacing SRC ethernet mac with host ethernet mac. I am interested in collecting this data for my project.

Is there any other way I can achieve this?

Commands used:

```
1. iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -i <host_interface_name>-p tcp -j TEE --gateway <container_ip>
2. iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination <container_ip:port>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. IPtables operate at the network layer and route the packet from the host where the rules were added. Therefore, we cannot avoid update of the source mac. I've tried using TPROXY, FORWARD, ACCEPT. Found the documentation for this at https://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html#lbDU
2. Achieved my requirement using : Linux TC. Simple inbuild Linux Traffic Controller can be used for shaping traffic moving through your interfaces.

> **https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/tc-mirred.8.html**